# Does Graphics`Mesh`SimplePolygonQ[] work for you?

Tags: functions, undocumented

`` Graphics`Mesh`SimplePolygonQ `` is an undocumented function.  I'm using Mathematica 7, and when I try:

```
Graphics`Mesh`SimplePolygonQ[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]
```

I just get:

> Graphics`Mesh`SimplePolygonQ[{{1, 0}, {0, $\sqrt{3}$, {-1, 0}}]

I posted a question and a respondent successfully used this function in the code of her answer.  Does anyone else have trouble using this function?  Any ideas why it won't work for me?

Comment: It takes a `Polygon[]` object as an argument.

Comment: @J.M.: p = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}] 
Graphics`Mesh`SimplePolygonQ[p]  Out[]:= Graphics`Mesh`SimplePolygonQ[Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]]

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: @J.M.: ...version 7.

Comment: I see. It would seem that this undocumented function is not in version 7 (I'm on version 8).

Comment: @J.M: I assume you are saying it works for you with ver. 8. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize this function is not available in version 7. (I thought it would be a fundamental one existing there long ago..) In that case maybe you have to implement the function yourself. For your reference, there are some relevant posts like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80798/detecting-polygon-self-intersection) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52733/equation-to-check-if-a-set-of-vertices-form-a-real-polygon).

Comment: @Silvia: My version wasn't important until that function was added.  I'll check out your links.  Thanks again!  :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: It would be worth checking if version 7 has ``Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ``